# Mail sent from Apple Mail is not show in Gmail's Sent folder

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

Apple Mail is not showing Sent Items in Gmail. The mails sent from Apple Mail are not in Gmail.

Comment: Is it set up as POP or IMAP?

Comment: These days, Exchange is also a possibility for Gmail.

Comment: Make sure you are using Gmail's SMTP server for outgoing mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that in your mail settings you have:

```
IMAP Path Prefix: [Gmail]
```

Under the Mailbox Behaviors tab in Accounts settings you have checked:

```
√ Store sent messages on the server
Delete sent messages when: Never
```

In the Sidebar of Mail, there should be grey subheadings for your accounts. Under the Grey subheading for your gmail account, you will find folders with titles of your gmail tags (e.g. `Important`, `Starred`, etc.) If you see one there called `Sent Mail`, select it, and select this menu item: `Mailbox` > `Use This Mailbox For` > `Sent`.

Comment: Does this then only apply to mails sent via the Gmail accounts or to all mails (sent e.g. via an additional iCloud account)?

Comment: √ Store sent messages on the server was already there. But second is not selectable. Take a look on this http://d.pr/i/suht